# How to add bootstrap modal popup in wordpress custom plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to add bootstrap modal pop-up in wordpress custom plugin. But the pop-up is coming. I am trying to bind the wp_ajax call response to popup on click of button.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this for your Popup Button 'onclick' event.

```
jQuery('#popup-btn').on('click', function(e){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{action:'your_function_name_here'},
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
            success: function(value) {
                jQuery('#popup-body').html(value);
                // you can also use .append or whatever based on your requirements
            }
        });
    });
```

And add these hooks too.

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_function_name_here',  'your_function_name_here' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_function_name_here', 'your_function_name_here' )
```